# Why I get the error "HTTP/1.0 463" in file_get_contents

Tags: php, webserver, user-agent

I'm trying to extract text content from the Habbo API, but I get the error Warning: file_get_contents (https://www.habbo.it/api/public/users?name=Adaara): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP / 1.0 463 HTTP request failed in file_get_contents.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = "https://www.habbo.it/api/public/users?name=Adaara";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['motto'];
?>
```

I expect the motto value of the array to be printed.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I am getting "*failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463*".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How solve HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 463?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733105/how-solve-http-request-failed-http-1-1-463)

Comment: @AlexBarker no, hosting based on linux

Answer (score -1):

Try cURL instead; it's pretty portable/dependable!

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url  = 'https://www.habbo.it/api/public/users?name=Adaara';

$handle = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array(
  $handle,
  [
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; PalmOS 3.0) EudoraWeb 2',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  ]
);

$data = curl_exec($handle);
$json = json_decode($data, true);

echo $json['motto'];
```