# System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (463).'

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make a tool that checks if a user exists but i get the error 463.

url im using (https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=123)

```
    Public Sub checkAccount()

        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=" + userToCheck)
        Dim repsonse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        Dim sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(repsonse.GetResponseStream)
        Dim Habboresult As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()

        If Habboresult.Contains("HTTP Status 404 – Not Found") Then
            'add user to listbox of available names
            freeName()
        Else
            'add user to listbox of names that are already in use
            usedName()
        End If

    End Sub
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIKOc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I’m not agree with your approach (in checking for new available user names), in order to fix your code and doing it running you have to add this instruction `.UserAgent` after New declaration of "request" Object (like code below shows)

```
  Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=123"), Net.HttpWebRequest)
  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"
```

Staying in context (always based in you code)  is wasted invoking all those classes for a downloaded string (are you shure you need to treat this as a string instead of bytes?? then if byte.length > 0…...).
Instead you can use three lines of code which are (for string data):

```
    Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent"  , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246")
    Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=123")
```

Or (for bytes data to convert in an image or testing it length)

```
    Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent"  , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246")
    Dim imageBytes = client.DownloadData("https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=123")
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956632/12808204 see if it helps.

I may be speaking from ignorance here, as networking isn't my forté, but the error range 452-499 isn't defined by an official RFC, and so what 463 means is likely implementation specific. Some cursory googling seems to support this, that this range is used for own defined error codes(But don't take my word as law on this). 4xx errors do generally refer to client errors though, i.e there may be an issue with your request. Maybe check that the string argument for System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create() is correct? Break it out to its own variable, and make sure userToCheck is actually defined when the function checkAccount() is called.
Without more info about the site or API you're interfacing with, I don't have more to give. Provide some more background info?